# Generate 16 bytes uniqueId ( or UUID ) and test it

Tags: java, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I need to create a unique ID. It has to be 16 bytes long.

I came across to java.util.UUID and try to use UUID.randomUUID(). But how to make sure that the generated UUID to be 16 bytes long?

In my JUnit I tried to test using

```
Assert.assertTrue(stringUUID.getBytes().length() ==16)
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to unit test JDK classes (unless you are writing code for the JDK). `java.util.UUID` will create proper 16 byte unique ids. Focus on your testing efforts on your own code instead.

And for more readily understandable test case output (in case of failed assertions) it is better to use assertEquals:

```
assertEquals("UUID has expected length", 16, stringUUID.getBytes().length());
```

This will fail, however, because the [string representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString%28%29) is longer than 16 bytes. What with hex-encoding and hyphens and all.

Comment: let's refine it: you don't need unit test for jdk, if you happen to _know_ what the given class does, otherwise it might come in handy ;)

Answer (score 4):

`UUID.randomUUID()` method generate a `type-4` UUID. That is `36 byte` long and have the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where x is any `hexadecimal` digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B. e.g. `f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479.`